# Avoid Windows 8 BCD File becoming missing and/or corrupt

Tags: windows-8, boot, bcd

I realise there are plenty of questions about BCD errors here however I feel mine is slightly different.

I had a missing BCD file so I couldn't boot. I have now solved this using a question I found on this website (hence why I am here now) but this is the second time my boot file has gone missing. Now, either he really doesn't like where he lives, or my BCD or Hard Drive have a fault. The first time this error occurred I re=installed windows and lost all my data. However, upon being able to rebuild my BCD this time and keep my data in tact, I am looking for advice on how to avoid this happening again. I have seen from google that this is often something to do with 3rd Party Software. However, since I lost my data, I have only downloaded two pieces of 3rd party software: Minecraft and Xsplit (A streaming program - I stream to twitch).

To clarify the question: What is the cause of Boot files going missing and how can it be avoided?

**EDIT 1:** I don't know if this is related (I imagine it is) but sometime when I go to start up my computer, all the lights will come on on my Mouse, my monitors will have signal and so on... But I just have a black screen with no cursor... I feel this is relevant.

**EDIT 2:** Following @DanielB 's request, here's the SMART data of my HD:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   094   091   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       2076
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       284
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       333
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       12
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       260
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   064   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       22 (Min/Max 13/29)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       281
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3283
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       12
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5506

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

The complete version is available on [my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rkhv5exrz035vjn/ST500LM012_HN-M500MBB_S2ZYJ9DDB30180_2014-04-20.txt).

Comment: Regular software can't even touch the BCD.

Comment: Oh well that shows how the internet can mislead people! @DanielB . So It is purely a hardware issue?

Comment: Probably. You could start by running [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) (at least 2 passes) and updating your question to include the SMART attributes of your hard disk. My preferred software for getting this data is [GSmartControl](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/).

Comment: Regular software can indeed affect the BCD - they just shouldn't and normally don't. They can't if they're running without admin privileges, though.

Comment: My first though was that the BCD was being corrupted due to these blue screens on startup. My PC often takes a long time to start and many times I have to turn it off and on again while it's booting as it gets stuck on a black screen for hours.

Comment: @Harvey - Slow startups are often caused by bad drivers.  You have lots of problems with BSOD which are more often caused by drivers.  These problems are also confirmed not to happen with a minimal configuration.  You will need to start with a minimal configuration and through trial and error find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hard drive might be going because of old age. You should buy a new hard drive, clone it (If possible) or take out the old drive, reinstall Windows, and be good to go.